# Using web camera on Qt 4.8

Tags: qt

Are there any ways to use web camera on qt 4.8?
On qt5.1.1 I saw example camera and I can use QCamera, but on qt4.8 I couldn't. Does somebody give examples?

Answer (score 0):

There are no native camera support in Qt4. Use Qt5 or some thirdpaty libraries. For example - GStreamer.

Comment: Can I use GStream in Windows 7?

Comment: Sorry, I see this lib first time.

Comment: Now I'm downloading this lib

Comment: Hi @Dmitry_Sazonov. Could you look at "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332560/cannt-compile-example-from-gstreamer-sdk"?(also my question)